# Is it possible to represent any positive integer with a sum of arbitrarily many distinct powers of $3$, $5$, and $7$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, exponentiation

My question is whether it is possible to represent every positive integer as the sum of any number of *unique* terms $b^x$, where $b\in\{3,5,7\}$, and integer $x \geq 0$.

(Note this would be trivially easy if using the prime base $2$ were allowed, as using additive terms $2^i$ is essentially how binary numbers are written.)

For example, in my scenario, $24$ has two valid representations:

$$ 3^1+3^2+5^1+7^1 = 3^0+3^2+5^0+5^1+7^0+7^1 = 24 $$

My instinct is that this shouldn't hold, but I haven't been able to find a counterexample yet or a convincing argument against it. I *have* been able to find empirical evidence that it doesn't work for almost all larger triples, e.g. $\{3,7,13\}$.

---

**Edit**

While Brian provided a nice counterexample to my $\{3,5,7\}$ case, it's natural to ask whether the same result will hold for $\{3,5,7,11\}$, or in general, for any finite subset of odd primes. Also remaining is the question of how to effectively determine the minimum counterexample for a given set.

Comment: $3^0$ + $5^0$. Exponents may be repeated, it's the entire term ($3^0$, say) that can't be repeated.

Comment: Oh okay, got your question now.

Comment: So, $3^0$ is considered a prime power of $3$?

Comment: The hard part is finding what combination of 5 and 7 powers fill in the 2's in the ternary representation

Comment: How in the representation $24=3^1+3^2+5^1+7^1$ does the condition "without using any single prime power twice" hold?

Comment: @PeterForeman - what is a perfect power?

Comment: aka power (base,exponent) ...

Comment: PeterForeman " it is possible to represent every positive integer as the sum of any number of prime powers of 3, 5, and 7," -- This is the OP's text. What do you make of it?

Comment: @PeterForeman  Does the number zero belong to $\mathbb{N}\backslash\{1\}$?

Comment: @PeterForeman I am sorry, I don't understand what you are saying. Is $3^1$ of the form $a^b$ with $b\in \mathbb{N}\backslash\{1\}$ or did the OP make clear that $1$ is also included somewhere and I just missed it?

Comment: The heading of the question makes some sense, but the text inside contradicts the heading in various ways, which renders it senseless to me. You start by asking "distinct powers" and then you give an example with repeating powers, both zero and one. You write in the text "prime powers of $3$,$5$ and $7$", which in English means $3^p$ or $5^p$ or $7^p$ where $p$ can take only prime values. But then you write powers of zero. So after guessing more or less what the question is, there can be various guesses as to what the answer can be.

Comment: not what a prime power is, that is a prime exponent ...https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_power

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee There's still an ambiguity here, since by that definition of "prime power" excludes $p^0$ (and also, if we simply appended it to the definition, would make $3^0 + 5^0$ inadmissible by the "distinct" qualification).  It's apparent to me that he meant "For each positive integer $n,$ there are finite subsets $I_3, I_5, I_7$ of the non-negative integers such that $$n = \sum_{i \in I_3} 3^i + \sum_{i \in I_5} 5^i + \sum_{i \in I_7} 7^i,$$ but this is inferred from the examples rather than from the definitions (in any case, this is the least strict interpretation, and it's false)

Comment: distinct base perhaps.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

$3^{60} - 1$ isn't achievable.

This can be seen as 
$$\lfloor\log_5(3^{60}-1)\rfloor = 40 \\ \lfloor\log_7(3^{60}-1)\rfloor = 33$$
but
$$\sum_{n=0}^{59} 3^n + \sum_{n=0}^{40} 5^n + \sum_{n=0}^{33} 7^n < 3^{60} - 1$$

---

**Edit:** Please also see the generalization given by user687721 in the comments.  If you can understand what is said there, you'll see what I did here is just a specific example of that procedure, and the resulting test given in the comment could be done by a grade-schooler with a pencil (whereas I needed a computer, or at least a decent calculator, for several steps)

Comment: Is this the lower bound, or just a simple case that works ?

Comment: It's definitely not the lower bound.  I was just searching for numbers of the form $n = 3^m - 1$ such that the fractional parts of $\log_5(n)$ and $\log_7(n)$ were close to $1.$  A few other possible candidates happened before $m=60,$ but this one looked the most promising (I had an early false positive, so I made my threshold for acceptance rather strict after going through the process of testing it)

Comment: What if the exponents have arbitrary gap between them instead of being serial numbers? E.g. $3^0  + 3^4  +3^{23} + \ldots$

Comment: @Nilos I don't think that matters. He's showed that even if you use every possible term up through $3^{59}$, $5^{40}$, and $7^{33}$, you won't reach $3^{60}$, and any larger terms will overshoot all by themselves. Very nice!

Comment: @Nilos For any subset $I \subseteq \{0,1,2,\ldots, 59\},$ $$\sum_{i \in I} 3^i \leq \sum_{n=0}^{59} 3^n$$ so we still have a strict inequality when compared to $3^{60}-1$

Comment: @BrianMoehring Do you think this same approach could be used to find a counterexample to any arbitrary (but finite) set of prime bases?

Comment: @Trevor If there were a counterexample for a given set of primes, then this method should find it.  However, obviously I did some computation here, so I don't know what theoretical results would replace my specific computation.  ------- As for whether a counterexample always exists in the general case you propose?  I have no clue.

Comment: Suppose that $p_i$ are a set of multiplicatively independent integers (distinct primes, for example). By Kronecker, one can find simlutaneous rational approximations $a_i/a_1$ to the quantities $\log(p_1)/\log(p_i)$ where the error is of the form $\epsilon/a_1$ for sufficiently small $\epsilon$. Then all the powers $(p_i)^{a_i}$ are the same order (up to multiplication by $1 + o(1)$),  taking $N$ to be $1$ less than the smallest one you win as long as $\sum \frac{1}{p_i - 1} < 1$ (e.g. $1/2+1/4+1/6=11/12$ in this case). This certainly deals with all triples of distinct primes not involving $2$

Comment: It would be nice to know the answer with 3,5,7,11. Since $1/2+1/4+1/6+1/10>1$, it could be possible

Comment: I find your answer highly intresting. I haven't seen anything like it before and would like to learn about it on an easier level. Is that some sort of magnitude analysis or how did you even think of such an approach?

Comment: @VasilyMitch Since $1/2+1/4+1/6+1/11=1+1/60$ is just barely greater than $1$, we cannot drop early terms in the geometric series $\frac1{p-1)=\sum p^{-k}$. In fact, we *need* $\frac13+\frac19+\frac1{27}$, as well as $\frac15+\frac1{25}$, and $\frac17+\frac1{49}$, and $\frac1{11}$. This reduces the range we can "play" with - perhaps enough to show that the claim also holds for 3,5,7,11?

Comment: 23 is not achievable.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet $23 = 3^0 + 3^2 + 5^0 + 5^1 + 7^1$

Comment: @BrianMoehring . $3^0$ and $5^0$ are not distinct.

Comment: @user687721 Could you share a source where one can read about that on an easier level? Thanks.

Comment: The "interesting" case is then $3, 5, 7, 13$ where $\sum 1/(p_i-1) = 1$ exactly.

Comment: @MichaelLugo I just came here to mention that. As I understand it, for $3,5,7,13$ to be able to cover every integer, they would therefore have to combine perfectly, like powers of $2$ do. Since we have trivial redundancy like $3^0=5^0$, we therefore know that $3,5,7,13$ can't be sufficient to represent any $n$.

Comment: @Trevor (revised comment) In the proof, we end up with sequences $a_{i,n}$ with $\forall i, \lim_{n\to\infty} a_{i,n} = 1$ where $$\sum a_{i,n}/(p_i-1) > \sum 1/(p_i-1),$$ so if $\sum 1/(p_i-1) \geq 1,$ then each element in the sequence is $>1,$ and we can't really conclude anything.  Moreover, if we disallow a finite number of prime powers, then the limits included in the argument don't change, so we can't use that type of argument by uniqueness.

Comment: Just for interest's sake, I'll pass on that I was able to find a counterexample for $\{3,5,7,17\}$ at $3^{115478}-1$. Still thinking about the $\{3,5,7,11 \text{ or } 13\}$ cases.

Comment: I wonder what is the smallest example $x\lt 3^{60} - 1$ that doesn't work.